# use of creating object inside of method that belongs to the same class in c#

Tags: c#

I have seen some of c# projects to get idea of c# coding. So i found object creation of class inside function, of the same class. Please explain me the reason and what exactly it will do, Following is sample code.

```
 class MainClass
{
    void TestChild()
    {
        //some code
    }
    void TestMethod()
    {
        MainClass object1 = new MainClass();
        object1.TestChild();
    }
}
```

Is it makes any difference of calling directly TestChild from TestMethod.

Comment: maybe you saw singleton pattern at work?

Comment: This example won't compile, as it stands as there's no declaration of the class `TestCase26827`. If you can show code that compiles, you've a better chance of getting an answer =)

Comment: Well, `TestChild` in this class is not `TestCase26827.TestChild`, so of course that's  a difference, both just have the same name. If `TestCase26827.TestChild` doesn't need any instance members of `TestCase26827` you can make it `static`. Otherwise ou need an instance. But you could store this instance as field in the `MainClass` if you only need this single one. Then you don't need to instantiate it always and you always use the same instance.

Comment: I can imagine this would be used when building a tree, where each `TreeNode` can create its child nodes - in that case one instance of `TreeNode` would create new `TreeNode` instances inside one of its methods.

Comment: by mistake given different class names, sorry

Comment: The second one needs more memory and is slower, because it creates an object

Answer (score 1):

While your code will not compile because of constructors must be named like the type it looks like a singleton implementation

```
using System;

public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

or another form of factory method

Answer (score 1):

To me, there is not much difference between this code and yours :

```
 class MainClass
{
    void TestChild()
    {
        //some code
    }
    void TestMethod()
    {
        TestChild();
    }
}
```

Unless the programmer wants to set up something in the constructor.

I am not sure why in comment section some people said your code cannot compile. It compiles well. (I have done that too last year without even noticing what I did).

The reason why declaring a new object to itself within TestMethod,  I believe, is to make sure TestMethod uses the right object to execute TestChild method in case of constructor overload.

Answer (score 0):

if you have TestChild method in your TestCase26827  class then the method will be invoked but not the method of MainClass